# How to get the previous column value using datareader

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi i am trying to get the previous value of my column so I can do a simple calculation my code is like that.

```
 ElseIf data_reader("PCT_HFO") < 0 Then
```

actual ROBS

```
Actual_ROBS = data_reader("Distance Run - NM")
+data_reader("PCT_Distance")-"Previous value of data_reader("PCT_Distance")".
```

New code
Previous_PCT_Distance = 0

DO while....
Actual_Distance = data_reader("Distance Run - NM") + data_reader("PCT_Distance") - Previous_PCT_Distance
Do stuff....
Previous_PCT_Distance = data_reader("PCT_Distance")
Loop

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your using a data reader you are looping though the rows so you just need a second variable previous value which is initially 0 for first record.

You then set this variable to the data reader value after you set Actual_ROBS

Comment: Awesome thought thank you so much just one more thing to clarify this.I initialiaze that variable with 0 and of course i have datareader in loop but how it will get previous value? It gets the previous one cause of the 0 at the start?

Comment: Initially value will be 0. So your calculation is Actual_ROBS = data_reader("Distance Run - NM")+data_reader("PCT_Distance")-Previous value

Comment: yea the thing i dont get is how will het the previous value from my table.It's because my new datareader has 0 as first value?

Comment: Ok first time trough the loop Previous value will initially be 0 but will be set to the field value after Actual_ROBS is set for the first time. Second time through Previous value will contain the last value read. You declare Previous value and set it to zero outside the loop

Comment: Ok what should the start value be? doesn't data_reader("PCT_Distance") give a non zero value? It will be this value that ends up as Previous Value first time though the loop

Comment: it gives a non zero value correct. i will post my code to see what i didgive me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Data readers are forward-only iterators. I suggest you use a Datatable, rather that data reader. But if u insist on using a data reader, you can use a new variable, say PreviousPCTDistance, that stores the copy of previous datareader value. Initialize the value of this variable to nothing or 0, for the first iteration. At the end of each loop, update this variable with the datareaders value, like :

```
PreviousPCTDistance = data_reader("PCT_Distance"),
```

So when your condition is satisfied, to get to use this previous value :

```
Actual_ROBS = data_reader("Distance Run - NM")+data_reader("PCT_Distance")- PreviousPCTValue
```

Comment: PreviousPCTDistance = data_reader("PCT_Distance") that variable will be initialised outside of the loop correct?And also i need to type this PreviousPCTDistance = data_reader("PCT_Distance") again after Actual_robs calculation right so i can get the new value of distance for the next loop?

Comment: @asbanoglou, Yes, Initialize PreviousPCTDistance outside the loop. 0 if its is a numeric value or nothing if it is non-numeric. And just before you end your loop, update this value : 
For 
'Conditions
PreviousPCTDistance = data_reader("PCT_Distance"),
Next